# Prime numbers less than a given number N

Tags: java, primes

So, I began [this challenge on CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/46/), which asks to print out the number of prime numbers less than any given integer N, where 0 < N < 4,294,967,295, ideally in O(N log N) time.  I came up with this solution:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int limit;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            line = line.trim();
            limit = Integer.valueOf(line);
            for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
                if (isPrime(i) || i == 2)
                    sb.append(i + ",");
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) 
            return false;
        for (int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2)
            if (n % i == 0) 
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm building up a string where I append all prime numbers less than N (which is passed by argument). Testing it, it works perfectly (or so it seems); submitting it, I get a "partially" status and score of 85. Don't know really what I'm messing up here...

Comment: To get \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$ time, you'll need to use a sieve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if all you care about is the *number* of primes below `N`, it can be done in `O(Sqrt(N) log(Sqrt(N))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The challenge states

> Print out the prime numbers **less** than a given number N

but you are iterating

```
for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
```

The ending condition should be `i < limit`.

- You need to check some edge cases:

  - `limit == 0` here you would get an exception at `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);`
  - `limit == 1` here you would get an exception at `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);`
  - `limit == 2` using the ending condition mentioned above you would get an exception at  at `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);` too
- If you start the loop (in main)  at `3` and increment `i` by `2` this will be faster and you wouldn't need `if (n % 2 == 0)`
- Using braces `{}` for single `if` statements and `loop bodies` will make your code less errorprone.
- importing the whole `java.io` namespace is to much. Restrict the imports to the classes you need.
- the `StringBuilder.append()` method returns a `StringBuilder` object. So instead of calling `sb.append(i + ",")` you should call `sb.append(i).append(",")`

**Refactoring**

The `while` loop

```
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    line = line.trim();
    limit = Integer.valueOf(line);
    if (limit > 2) {
         sb.append(2).append(",");
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < limit; i += 2){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            sb.append(i).append(",");
        }
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

and the `isPrime()` method

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

in this way `isPrime()` **would** return true for each int `n < 3` but this is for this case perfectly fine, because this is a private method which is only called in this specific szenario given strong borders.

Comment: Right about now I'm feeling a bit idiot for overlooking the '<=' issue... of course it was that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The challenge states that N can be as large as 2<sup>32</sup>-2.  However, an `int` in Java is a signed 32-bit type, holding a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1.  Therefore, your program is subject to overflow.

The simplest solution is to use `long` everywhere.  In Java 8, you also have the option of using an `int`, but dutifully using methods such as `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` and `Integer.compareUnsigned()` everywhere, so that the 32 bits are interpreted as unsigned.  However, I don't see any reason to uglify your code just to save 32 bits, so I recommend using `long`.